# Solving $2^x=x^3$ Algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

> How can I solve $2^x=x^3$ algebraically?

I could take $\log_2(\cdot)$ on both sides, but I'd still be stuck.

Comment: You can rewrite it as $e^{\ln \frac{1}{x}} \ln \frac{1}{x}=-\frac{\ln 2}{3}$, then apply the lambert $W$ function.  I think that’s the best you can do in terms of algebraic manipulation.

Comment: What is the Lambert W function?

Comment: Basically, a function $W(x)$ that satisfies $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$. That means the solution to $xe^x=2$ is $W(2)$. For a more precise definition see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.

Comment: Could I use a change of base formula?

Comment: There’s nothing stopping you, but at the end of the day I don’t think you’ll be able to reach a closed form solution (of finely many terms) without the use of special functions. I say finitely many terms because you can express $x$ as a series, for example.

Comment: If you do not use Lambert function, only numerical methods would do the work.

Answer (score 3):

As  Ahmed S. Attaalla commented, the only analytic solutions are given in terms of Lambert function, namely
$$x_1=-\frac{3 W_0\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{3}\right)}{\log (2)}\qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=-\frac{3 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{3}\right)}{\log (2)}$$ and you can evaluate them using the series expansion given in the Wikipedia page.

If you do not want or cannot use Lambert function, only numerical methods would do the job. Start graphing your function and you will notice that the roots are around $1$ and $10$. Using them a strating guesses, use Newton method to get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.00000 \\
 1 & 1.61969 \\
 2 & 1.41482 \\
 3 & 1.37493 \\
 4 & 1.37347
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 10.0000 \\
 1 & 9.94143 \\
 2 & 9.93954
\end{array}
\right)$$ which are the solutions for six significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

This equation follows the general equation 
$$a^x = x^{b}$$
and can be solved, for $a \neq 1$, as follows:
\begin{align}
a^{x} &= x^{b} \\
e^{x \, \ln a} &= x^{b} \\
x^{b} \, e^{- x \, \ln a} &= 1 \\
x \, e^{- x \, \ln a/b} &= 1 \\
- \frac{x \, \ln a}{b} \, e^{- x \, \ln a/b} &= - \frac{\ln a}{b} \\
u \, e^{u} &= - \frac{\ln a}{b} \, \hspace{5mm} u = - \frac{x \, \ln a}{b} \\
u = - \frac{x \ln a}{b} &= W_{0}\left(- \frac{\ln a}{b}\right) \\
x &= - \frac{b}{\ln a} \, W_{0}\left(- \frac{\ln a}{b}\right),
\end{align}
where $W_{0}(x)$ is the primary branch of the Lambert W-function which is defined as the solution to the equation $W(x) \, e^{W(x)} = x$. Note that in the case $a=1$ the solution is $x = e^{2 \pi i/b}$.

For the problem proposed it is determined that:
$$2^{x} = x^{3} \, \text{ leads to } \, x = - \frac{3}{\ln 2} \, W\left(- \frac{\ln 2}{3}\right).$$